# Nvidia GPU Upgrade To Geforce RTX 2060

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, nvidia, hardware, gpu

OS: CentOS7

I currently have

```
[orca@orcacomputers ~]$ nvidia-detect
kmod-nvidia
[orca@orcacomputers ~]$ nvidia-detect -v
Probing for supported NVIDIA devices...
[10de:11c6] NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti]
```

Now, I have a new [GPU Geforce RTX 2060](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/)

I am curious do I simply boot down the machine, install new hardware and reboot and `kmod-nvidia` will pick up the new gpu driver? Or do I download the driver from the Nvidia site?

Reason I ask is I see [kmod-nvidia](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kmod-nvidia) looks like it was updated last in 2015 so I'm not certain if the kmod-nvidia will have the updated/working driver.  I'm speculating but outcome is undeterminable.

I tried looking at a list of all supported devices [here](ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/352.79/README/supportedchips.html)  but the url isn't loading from [the page](http://elrepo.org/tiki/nvidia-detect)

Then is there a way to see all listed drivers in the kmod-nvidia from the cli?

Comment: Do note that most of your questions titles (but also comments, e.g. your post about measuring GPUs performance) aren't clear about what you're asking (or saying). For better help, do tell what distro you are using and which version of it it is.

Answer (score 1):

There's no chance that these `kmod-nvidia` drivers will work with your RTX 2060, these are just too old (last release was 2015, RTX 2060 is from 2019).

Just use the latest proprietary Nvidia drivers that comes with your distro, since downloading them from the website will be very prone to incompatibilities later. If your distro is too old, you really should update it if you can.

**Update**: I've just saw your edit.

Since you're on CentOS, this changes everything. So it's ultimately safe to download it from Nvidia's website, but only the "Game Ready Driver" are good since there's no "Linux Long Lived", and "Linux Short Lived" are garbage for reliability.

But still, better update your OS, or switch to something else than CentOS like Debian or Xubuntu LTS since CentOS is going the rolling-release path, which means it's not a stable and staged distro anymore.

Comment: I thought the proprietary drivers for CentOS7 are ElRepo.  Can you please explain in Penguin Terms to me: "Just use the latest proprietary Nvidia drivers that comes with your distro,"